# Trigger LogStash pipeline from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Is there any easy way to configure it from Kibana? I have full control of the LogStash server and running Kibana on Elastic cloud

The only possible route I can think of is to create a custom button on Kibana that call a web service, setup a web service on LogStash server that manually start logstash on call

Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Could you please describe your use case in more details? Usually logstash is installed next to your business service and always "up-and-running" being ready to ingest logs data to ElasticSearch so that later on you could consume the data in kibana... What is LogStash server?

Comment: @Mark Currently I have full control to the server that install Logstash. But Logstash is configured to poll the database at a specified interval (once a few minutes) I would like to overcome that in the case I need the data updated up-to-this-second

Comment: There is no trigger from Kibana to start external applications. But why do not run Logstash as a service on your server?

Comment: Does that solves the issue of logstash only pull the data from database following defined cron trigger? ( I am using the schedule in jdbc input )